# Tap on gridviewitem should scrolls it to top left windows 8

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-8, scrollviewer

I am in a situation where I have following structure

```
<GridView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" >
     <Grid>
       <Gridview>
       ...
       </GridView>
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
      <Gridview>
       ...
      </GridView>
    </Grid>
      .
      .
      .
 </GridView
```

Now what I need is on selectionchange event of any CHILD gridview, it should scroll parent grid to top right so that tapped item's gridview will be shown at first position.
Like following image 
[image]

I am trying using

```
 var scrollViewer1 = GVmain.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
 scrollViewer1.ScrollToHorizontalOffsetWithAnimation(moveGridView);
```

After so many hit and trials I could't able to come up with any formula that will set "moveGridView" value so that it can scrolls the gridview to left as it required.

Answer (score 0):

If your main GV is not virtualized, then all child GVs are in the visual tree and so if are using my toolkit you can check the position of the child GV relative to the main GV like this:

```
var pos = childGV.GetPosition(relativeTo: GVmain);
var scrollViewer1 = GVmain.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
scrollViewer1.ScrollToHorizontalOffsetWithAnimation(pos.X);
```

Note, if you are targeting Windows 8.1 - you should avoid using `ScrollToHorizontalOffsetWithAnimation()` as the built-in `ChangeView()` method should perform better and also supports animation.

Comment: Hey Filip, I tried this , but it always takes the gridview to scroll to End , seems like there is need to divide pos.X with some number as it gives very large value.

Any idea about that?

Comment: I am using childGV.GetPosition() and dividing it with the total width of a column including margin, it shows strange behaviour : When I click to a column first Time, it does not scrolls to left but it's scroll bar's width gets smaller, when I click it second time , Same thing happens and it's scroll bar's width gets more smaller , now at third time it does scrolls to the left as I want .